# IList<IList<int>> result = new List<IList<int>>()

Tags: c#, oop, generics, arraylist, interface

This is something I have been confused with for quite a while now. Not sure if it's a C# specific problem or some simple OOP fact I am not able to grasp.

```
IList<IList<int>> result = new List<IList<int>>(); //Works Fine
IList<IList<int>> result2 = new IList<IList<int>>();     //Gives Error because we cannot initialize interface
IList<IList<int>> result3 = new List<List<int>>();       //Gives Error please explain why
IList<IList<int>> result4 = new IList<List<int>>();      //Gives Error please explain why
```

For the above lines of code can someone please explain why line 3 and 4 are wrong and line 1 is right?

Comment: Because this declaration is syntaxically incorrect `IList<int>>`. You also can't assign list of list of int values to just list of int. They are different types

Comment: `int` and `List<int>` are not same:)

Comment: I bet they should all be `IList<IList<int>>` on the left, then this question is reasonable.

Comment: @djv sorry my bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The so-called duplicate does not even contain the word interface nor is here a derived class involved. Sometimes it's really strange what is considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Because in

```cs
R<S> = T<U>;
```

- `T : R`. All your examples satisfy this. `List : IList`, `List = List`, and `IList = IList`.
- `T : new()`. This disqualifies the Interfaces in 2 and 4.
- `U = S`. The generic types must match, not be derivable. This disqualifies 3.

Since U = S, write it as this

```cs
R<S> = new T<S>;
```

then it's more clear. These four will satisfy the above requirements

```cs
IList<IList<int>> result = new List<IList<int>>();
List<IList<int>> result2 = new List<IList<int>>();   
IList<List<int>> result3 = new List<List<int>>(); 
List<List<int>> result4 = new List<List<int>>();
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by:- T : new(). This disqualifies the Interfaces in 2 and 4.

Comment: @anjanikumaragrawal you must be able to create a new instance. You can't do that with interfaces.

Answer (score -2):

`IList<int>` and `IList<IList<int>>` aren't the same thing. You can't assign one to the other just like you can't assign a string to an int.

And the syntax is wack too. Every `<` needs an `>`, and vice-versa.

If you really want to do this you need

```
List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
```

Notice we are instantiating the concrete type, not the interface.

Comment: No I cannot do that because I sometimes get questions on Leetcode and the return type of expected response is:
    IList<IList<int>>

Comment: @AnjaniKumarAgrawal `List<List<int>>` is an instance of `IList<IList<int>>` because List implements IList. You can't instantiate an `IList`, because it is an interface not a concrete type. `List` is the concrete implementation of `IList`. If its requiring an `IList` then `List` qualifies. Anything that implements `IList` would qualify. This is the foundational basis of Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control. Anything expecting an interface `IList` MUST accept any concrete implementation of `IList`.

Comment: `List is the concrete implementation of IList`  No.  `List<T>` is *a* concrete implementation of `IList<T>`.  It is not *the* implementation.  `This is the foundational basis of Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control.`  I think you mean Object Oriented Programming.  None of this has anything to do with DI/IoC.